# Rugged battery powered 4G/LTE WiFi hotspot with internal antenna, recommendations?

Tags: wifi, router, battery-life, 4g

I've been searching a lot on the internet for a rugged battery powered 4G/LTE WiFi hotspot with internal antenna. Can't seem to find any suitable alternatives. Need to know if anybody else knows about a possible suitable product.

Minimum specs:

- Water resistant (must tolerate rain)
- Operating temperature -20 to +40 C (-4 to +104 F)
- 4G/LTE
- Wifi broadcast of 4G/LTE connection
- Internal antenna
- Powered by rechargeable internal battery
- Minimum 8 hours battery time on full load
- Price below 600 USD / 600 EUR (somewhat flexible)

Thanks in advance!